# Parser - Segmentation fault when calling yytext

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lex

My parser is recognizing the grammar and indicating the correct error line using yylineno. I want to print the symbol wich caused the error.

```
int yyerror(string s)
{
  extern int yylineno;  // defined and maintained in lex.yy.c
  extern char *yytext;  // defined and maintained in lex.yy.c

  cerr << "error: " << s << " -> " << yytext << " @ line " << yylineno << endl;
  //exit(1);
}
```

I get this error when I write something not acceptable by the grammar:

> error: syntax error -> Segmentation fault

Am I not supposed to used yytext? If not what variable contains the symbol that caused the syntax error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using *lex* or *flex*? If you're using *lex*,`yytext` is a `char[],` not a `char*.`

**EDIT** If you aren't using *flex* you should be, it is superior in every way and has been from the moment of its appearance nearly 30 years ago. *lex* was obsoleted on that day.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the version of lex you are using, `yytext` may be an array or may be a pointer.  Since it is defined in a different compilation unit, if it is an array and you declare it as a pointer, you won't see any error messages from the compiler or linker (linker generally don't do type checking).  Instead it will treat the first several characters in the array as a pointer and try to dereference it and probably crash.

If you are using flex, you can add a `%pointer` declaration to the first section of your .l file to ensure that it is a pointer and not an array